# Check All box does not work with Jquery DataTable version 1.10.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a jquery dataTable with 3 columns (check box column, userId, full name).  The 'check_all' check box worked fine (meaning all the rows were checked when the 'check_all' was clicked) when I used it with jquery.dataTables.js and jquery.dataTables.min.js version 1.9.4.  However, I have to use dataTable version 1.10.5 in order to use the "draw()" function.  But once I started using the new version, the check_all checkbox stopped working, the alert() inside the .click() didn't get invoked.  I tried to put the .click function inside the $(document).ready(), but didn't fix the issue.  Anybody has any idea ?  Thanks!!

Script:

```
 $('#check_all').click(function() 
 {      
    alert("here");
    var oTable = $('#users').DataTable();
  });
```

HTML part:

```
<DIV id ="tablePanel">
   <table class="userTable" cellpadding="4" rules="all" border="1" id="users">      
      <THEAD>                                                                 
         <TR>                                    
           <th><input type="checkbox" id ="check_all"  class="call-checkbox" name="check_all">Select  users</th>
           <th>User Id</th>
           <th>Full Name</th> 
         </TR>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY>
      <TBODY>
    </table>   
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing ")" on the click event handler function.  You should also ensure that any bindings occur after the DOM is ready by placing them inside jQuery's document.ready() function.

The full syntax is $(document).ready(function () { .. }); but it can be shortened to $(function() { ... });

```
$(function () {
    $('#check_all').click(function () {
        alert("here");
        var oTable = $('#users').DataTable();
    });
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/qe0ckve8/

Comment: How is this related to changing from one version of DataTables to another?

Comment: It may not be, but that typo will prevent the handler from being set up properly.

Comment: To be fair, your answer didnt mention the typo before : )

Comment: I just tried to add the $function(), but still not able to invoke the alert within the click.  I also fixed the typo on the original post.

Comment: Try the updated code in my answer and in the fiddle.

Comment: no it doesn't work.  If I change it to onclick within the <input>, it would work, but got other problems which I posted another post.